# alt-middle mouse to resize - stuck on resize

Tags: mouse, resize

Occasionally I have an issue where when I alt-middle click and drag to resize the window, the mouse cursor gets stuck in resize mode, and nothing I do will allow the mouse cursor to get out of this. I can alt-tab to switch apps, but I can't click to close windows or otherwise get unstuck. Sometimes mashing random keys on the keyboard will fix it, but unsure exactly what combination. Otherwise I have to forcibly reboot or restart X.

Anyone else had this issue?

System is Ubuntu 14.04.03 LTS

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> seems to get the mouse point out of resize mode.

Comment: Hrm, that does not work for me, though I got into the same problem as you via the same way.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is working for me when I resize terminal window:
close the resized window Alt F4, open or go to another terminal window, click inside. Cursor will get back to normal.
I had problems only with terminal windows.